# How to set up HTTP/SOCKS5 tunneling proxy on Windows using freeSSHd?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel

freeSSHd was set up on the server. Putty successfully connecting to server over SSH. I have tried to configure tunneling for SOCKS5 and HTTP but it failed to work. Especially was tested on Opera where proxy was set to `127.0.0.1` and port `1080`.

I am trying to set up SOCKS5 proxy/tunneling in putty that way: `Connection>SSH>Tunnels` there I set:

`Source port` 1080

`Destination` 127.0.0.1

```
Dynamic

IPv4
```

Why SOCKS5 proxy tunneling is not working?

---

UPDATE:

Firefox writes "The proxy server is refusing connections"

---

UPDATE2:

Set up all the same but left blank `Destination`.

Firefox messages:

**The connection was reset**

```
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

---

UPDATE 3

Firefox refuses to connect to `google.com` with error : `The connection was reset`. Opera is not working. (it appeased to work when it reseted proxy config)

---

UPDATE 4

How putty deals with network connections? In this cmd at some times there was `TCP 127.0.0.1:1080 LISTENING`. What are the rest 2 TCP connections with 1080 port?
CLIENT CMD:
[image: CLIENT]

---

UPDATE 5:

freeSSHd config on server:

[image]

---

UPDATE 6:

I made `Deluge` torrent client successfully function over SSH tunnel (using SOCKS5)! Internet browsers still being stubborn and not connecting to web (neither SOCKS5 or HTTP proxy settings is working).

Comment: Did you try without destination? Any particular error message?

Comment: Regarding update 3: if Opera works, the tunnel is working then, which is good news. You're using Firefox standard proxy configuration? You put 127.0.0.1:1080 as SOCKS5 proxy, nothing for the other proxy types?

Comment: The ssh connection itself is working? (You can interact with the server?) What is the freeSSHd configuration?

Comment: SSH to server works fine. I can interact with the server.

Comment: When putty starts (with all ssh tunnel configuration) it is not opening any 1080 ports on localhost. I must do it in order to set up tunnel. Right?

Comment: I think the problem is with the tunnel config on the server side, not on putty side. The putty setup looks good, and your last screenshot shows that it is effectively listening on port 1080. Also communication between the putty client and the freeSSHd is apparently working, so the last missing step is the tunnel being open in freeSSHd. I'm not using this software, but I'm trying to find information, and to be frank, seing the few first pages of google, the tunneling support in freeSSHd seems very poor! What does the 'tunneling' tab in freeSSHd config shows?

Comment: What tunnel options would you suggest as a replacement for freeSSHd which will work on Windows 7?

Comment: It seems to me that Putty client cannot set up port 1080 to listen on this(client) machine. Probably it did one time (as seen on screenshot) but now nothing happens. I am not very familiar with Windows network stack. Maybe it has some specifics I should consider...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13959/discussion-between-bonob-and-rcola)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean to access an external SOCKS proxy from windows, here you go. If you meant setting up a SSH server in windows, cygwin can do this with `sshd`.

In windows, cygwin makes this easy, but if you don't have cygwin already, here are PuTTY instructions.

Set it up like this:
replace port 2222 with 22 or whatever your port for SSH is. Leaving it blank should work too. 22 is the default, but I had it on a non-standard port. Replace 127.0.0.1 here with your actual address.

[image: Setting up puTTY - 1]


Here, LEAVE the 127.0.0.1 where it is. It is SUPPOSED to be there. You can change 8080 to whatever port you want the SOCKS proxy on.

[image: Setting up puTTY - 2]

Be sure to set the login username to whatever yours is. Mine is 'mobile' on my iphone, which I was using when i made this example for the apple stack exchange.
[image: Setting up puTTY - 3]

If you want, you can then save a profile for this, to avoid setting it all back up each time you have a problem. This is done in the 'session' section at the very top.

### Linux/Unix/BSD/Solaris/OSX/HP-UX/whatever I'm still missing

You can run `ssh -D 8080 user@address`

Now, you need to open your web browser of choice; I use firefox, so I will use it as an example. I have used chrome and opera, but as I do not like them and do not currently have them installed, I cannot presently use it for an example. But you set it up as a SOCKS proxy, regardless of browser.

These screenshots were done with a forwarded X11, so the fonts are ugly, but pay it no mind.
First, go to the preferences window (`tools -> options` or `edit -> preferences`, depending on OS). Then, go to `Advanced -> Network -> Settings...`.
[image: Firefox Configuration 1]

Use the following configuration for the browser.

[image: Firefox Configuration 2]

## Problems and Solutions

### Problem:

My app doesn't allow setting a SOCKS proxy.

### Solution:

I have had this problem with games like Minecraft. Here's some fixes.

For minecraft, I added a argument to `ssh`. I regularly play on the nerd.nu reddit minecraft servers (reddit.com/r/mcpublic). Since minecraft 1.6, SSH tunneling and SOCKS proxies set as command line arguments haven't worked. You used to be able to add java parameters `-DSocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DSocksProxyPort=8080` and it would work. Now, however, the solution isn't quite as nice, but it does work.

When you start `ssh`, instead of `ssh -D 8080 user@address`, do
`ssh -D 8080 -L 127.0.0.1:25565:p.nerd.nu:25565 user@address`. 
 Then, when you want to connect to the server, instead add the URL `127.0.0.1:25565` to your list of servers! The remote server will appear on 127.0.0.1/localhost thanks to the miracle of SSH tunneling!

For other programs/games, the same rule applies. If you can't set a SOCKS proxy and nothing else works, just add `-L 127.0.0.1:<port>:<remote URL to access>:<remote port>`.

There is nothing forcing you to use the same port on `127.0.0.1` that you would normally, so I could have, for example, mapped `p.nerd.nu:25565` to `127.0.0.1:1025` and the game wouldn't care as long as I specified the port. Not all programs are so lenient, but it's useful to remember.